# Multiple Bar plot in one graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

I'm a beginner to R.

I need to create a graph like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/az56z.jpg

I dont know how to produce my entire dataset. The basic idea is some exon id would have more than one subgroups. I need to plot all the values in bar plots within that exon id

How can I do that in R?

Comment: plotting your data should come secondary to producing/compiling the data needed. I recommend breaking this down into smaller chunks and searching for help on specific topics, and asking questions as they come up. It is not reasonable to expect someone to create something like that graph you linked to without any sense of where the data is coming from or how you are interacting with it.

Comment: Check out tutorials here (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html) and here (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done a plot like this myself but I think the 'lattice' package is what you would be after. You can get the pdf guide from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html.

Comment: `ggplot2` also supports easy faceting of plots based on a variable(s).