# Multiple Bar plot in one graphs in R

Tags: r, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Bar plot in one graphs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085941/multiple-bar-plot-in-one-graphs-in-r)

Hi,

I'm a beginner to R.

I need to create a graph like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/az56z.jpg

I dont know how to produce my entire dataset. The basic idea is some exon id would have more than one subgroups. I need to plot all the values in bar plots within that exon id

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do R in my stats class last semester.  For the future if you google r-code it yields better results.  I know that just searching for r always makes annoying results.

If you set up your dataset as a value say

```
library(gdata)
dataset = read.csv('blahh.csv')
barplot(dataset, main="blahh", 
     xlab="blahh")
```